# Docker-Compose container communication for microservices via Caddy v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, caddy, docker-network

I have the following architecture:

Docker with Linux-Containers on Windows

- A NodeJS microservice called **register** listens inside the docker-network on port **3100**
- a **Caddy** Container image from https://hub.docker.com/r/abiosoft/caddy/ for internal routing
- a **Mongo** Container image

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    build: ./data
    container_name: "mongodb"
    hostname: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    logging:
      driver: none
  router:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./router/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./router/etc/:/etc/
      - ./router/.config/:/.config/
      - ./router/home:/home/caddy/
    ports:
      - "3000:8080"
    cap_add:
      - CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
  register:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./development.docker
      args:
        SERVICE_NAME: register
    container_name: "register"
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
```

**CaddyFile.json**

```
  "admin": {
    "listen": "0.0.0.0:2019"
  },
  "apps": {
    "http": {
      "servers": {
        "srv0": {
          "listen": ["0.0.0.0:8080"],
          "routes": [{
            "handle": [{
              "handler": "reverse_proxy",
              "transport": {
                "protocol": "http"
              },
              "upstreams": [
                {
                  "dial":"register:3100"
                }
              ]
            }],
            "match": [{
              "path": ["/register", "/register/*"]
            }],
            "terminal": true
          }, {
            "handle": [{
              "handler": "subroute",
              "routes": [{
                "handle": [{
                  "handler": "file_server",
                  "hide": ["/etc/caddy/Caddyfile"],
                  "root": "/home/caddy/web/" # index.html is shown when accessing localhost:3000
                }]
              }]
            }],
            "match": [{
              "path": ["/"]
            }],
            "terminal": true
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Behaviour**

GET-Request to localhost:3000 shows index.html --> works

GET-Request to localhost:3000/register should return a JSON-Object

**Actual Behaviour**

[I get the following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvkca.png)

```
router_1    | 2020/01/30 12:24:20.688   ERROR   http.log.error  dial tcp: lookup register on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address     {"request": {"method": "GET", "uri": "/register/", "proto": "HTTP/1.1", "remote_addr": 
"172.18.0.1:43612", "host": "localhost:3000", "headers": {"Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate, br"], "Connection": ["keep-alive"], "Content-Type": ["application/json"], "User-Agent": ["PostmanRuntime/7.22.0"], "Accept": ["*/*"], "Cache-Control": ["no-cache"], "Postman-Token": ["a7558f06-c099-4bbe-bee9-97c50a8910b8"]}}, "status": 502, "err_id": "5nm6udifm", "err_trace": "reverseproxy.(*Handler).ServeHTTP (reverseproxy.go:362)"}
```

I restarted docker-compose multiple times, tried to change DNS settings and strangely it worked in rare cases but just once.
As far as I know, all the containers are able to ping each other in the network, so there must be some kind of connection between them. As mentioned before, I am trying to run this network with Linux containers on a Windows machine. I also tried it on multiple Linux systems and everything worked just fine.

I am not sure, whether it is a DNS-Problem or something else?

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

here are the logs

```
mongodb     | WARNING: no logs are available with the 'none' log driver
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:42:26.969   INFO    using provided configuration    {"config_file": "/etc/caddy/caddyfile.json", "config_adapter": "json5"}
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:42:26.982   INFO    admin   admin endpoint started  {"address": "0.0.0.0:2019", "enforce_origin": false, "origins": ["0.0.0.0:2019"]}
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:42:26.984   INFO    tls     cleaned up storage units
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:42:26 [INFO][cache:0xc000324dc0] Started certificate maintenance routine
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:42:27.099   INFO    autosaved config        {"file": "/.config/caddy/autosave.json"}
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:42:27.099   INFO    serving initial configuration
register    |
register    | > register@0.0.1 start:linux /app/services/register
register    | > nodemon --watch src --ext ts --exec 'nest build && node ./dist/services/'$npm_package_name'/src/main'
register    |
register    | [nodemon] 2.0.2
register    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
register    | [nodemon] watching dir(s): src/*/
register    | [nodemon] watching extensions: ts
register    | [nodemon] starting `nest build && node ./dist/services/register/src/main`
register    | (node:30) [DEP0091] DeprecationWarning: crypto.DEFAULT_ENCODING is deprecated.
register    | (node:30) [DEP0010] DeprecationWarning: crypto.createCredentials is deprecated. Use tls.createSecureContext instead.
register    | (node:30) [DEP0011] DeprecationWarning: crypto.Credentials is deprecated. Use tls.SecureContext instead.
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +50ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +2ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
register    | (node:29) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the
new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
register    | (node:29) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseCoreModule dependencies initialized +48ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +3ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +2ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +12ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/register}: +33ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/create, POST} route +16ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +16ms
register    | [Nest] 29   - 01/30/2020, 1:42:45 PM   [Main] REGISTRATION LISTENING 2
router_1    | 2020/01/30 13:43:08.235   ERROR   http.log.error  dial tcp: lookup register on [::1]:53: dial udp [::1]:53: connect: cannot assign requested address       {"request": {"method": "POST", "uri": "/register/create", "proto": "HTTP/1.1", "remote_addr": "172.20.0.1:53036", "host": "localhost:3000", "headers": {"Postman-Token": ["c3b7a4b1-d424-4fe0-8809-5d9fc38dd9dc"], "Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate"], "Connection": ["keep-alive"], "Content-Type": ["application/json"], "Cache-Control": ["no-cache"], "User-Agent": ["PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"], "Accept": ["/"], "Content-Length": ["429"]}}, "status": 502, "err_id": "qx319czc0", "err_trace": "reverseproxy.(*Handler).ServeHTTP (reverseproxy.go:362)"}
```

Unfortunately using *depends_on* in docker-compose.yaml does not work.

Comment: what is the output of `docker-compose up`? (If you used `-d` you can see the log with `docker-compose logs`). My first guess, is that you need to add `depends_on` to your docker-compose.yml https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: @wotanii I updated the thread with the logs.

Comment: are all ports you use on the host machine free when you start the containers? Also make sure no other instances of the containers are running, which may block ports, You can use `lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN` to chek if a port is blocked (port 8080 in this case)